# how to use "find_in_set" in cakephp find method

Tags: cakephp

I have a table in which comma seprated id of another table i want to use the following query in cakephp in proper form with find function

```
"select * from special_offers where find_in_set('".$storeId."', stores) and user_id = '". $userId ."'";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use like this

```
$data = $this->SpecialOffer->find('all',array('conditions' => array('SpecialOffer.user_id' => $userId ,'FIND_IN_SET(\''. $storeId .'\',SpecialOffer.stores1)')));
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to use the array syntax (for automatic escaping etc): `FIND_IN_SET(?, SpecialOffer.stores1)' => array($storeId)`,

Comment: ya we can use array but we use array if we have array of ids and math it with a single id on the database but i have a single id from the url and coma seprated ids in the databse thats why i need this one ("find_in_set")

Comment: @ShivomkaraChaturvedi , How to make the query dynamic, means I want to use the comma separated ids, (during fetching multiple records using of $storeId(variable) is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid SQL injection, it is also possible to bind the parameter like this:

```php
$data = $this->SpecialOffer->find('all')
    ->where([
        'SpecialOffer.user_id' => $userId,
        'FIND_IN_SET(:storeId, SpecialOffer.stores1)',
    ])
    ->bind(':storeId', $storeId, 'integer');
```