# I need to pull data based on its exact sequence in an array

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Below is my code and I want to pull the data based on the sequence 3, 10 then 7, how can I do that? so far it pulls first 10, then 7, then 3.

```
<code>
        $cars = $this->car->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'car.id' => array(3, 10, 7)
        ),
        'limit' => 3, 
        'order' => array('car.id' => 'desc')
    ));

    </code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to order the result by their respective position in the array. In this case MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function can help you.

You may add the following order by statement:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(car.id,'3,10,7')
```

**Note:** You need convert this order by statement in your equivalent `cake php mysql` query.

> MySQL FIND_IN_SET() returns the position of a string if it is present
>   (as a substring) within a list of strings. The string list itself is a
>   string contains substrings separated by ‘,’ (comma) character.
>
> This function returns 0 when search string does not exist in the
>   string list and returns NULL if either of the arguments is NULL.

[FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

**Sample Input:**

**query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
```

---

```
id
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

**Output:**

**query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE cars.id IN (3,10,7)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(cars.id,'3,10,7')
```

---

```
id
3
10
7
```

Check the [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee3a7a/3/0)

**Edit:**

I don't know `CAKE PHP syntax` in building mysql query.

But The equivalent query in `cake php mysql` may be something like that:

```
$cars = $this->car->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'car.id' => array(3, 10, 7)
        ),
        'limit' => 3, 
        'order' => array(FIND_IN_SET('car.id' , '3,10,7'))
    ));
```

Comment: I need in cakephp code not mysql code plz. Plus I tried the FIND_IN_SET and I had an error  Call to undefined function FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: I don't know `cake php`. Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545045/how-to-use-find-in-set-in-cakephp-find-method). It might help you.

Comment: Please look at the edit section in my answer. It might help also. @Dani

Comment: Subrata, it is still not working, can you verify your code, I think there is something missing there.