# How can i show the result using IN clause?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `id` IN (83,84);
```

Above query give me the result in asc order according to query but when i am change the order like 83 is replace by 84 and 84 is replace by 83 it again give me asc order result. i want to show the result according to query.

Comment: The order in IN is not related to the order how the records are shown

Comment: `order by FIELD(id,83,84)` and if you want 84 to be the first then `order by FIELD(id,84,83)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` in order by clause:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM `students` 
WHERE `id` IN (83,84)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,'83,84')
```

**Brief note on `FIND_IN_SET`:**

**Description**

`MySQL FIND_IN_SET()` returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings. The string list itself is a string contains substrings separated by ‘,’ (comma) character.

This function returns 0 when search string does not exist in the string list and returns `NULL` if either of the arguments is `NULL`.

**Syntax**

```
FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)
```

**Arguments**

```
Name            Description
search string   A string which is to be looked for in following list of arguments.
string list     List of strings to be searched if they contain the search string.
```

[**Related post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678430/i-need-to-pull-data-based-on-its-exact-sequence-in-an-array)

<sub>Alternatively you can use `FIELD()` function to accomplish that</sub>

Comment: **To whom it may concern:** Couldn't find the reason of being downvoted. It's one of ways I swear! would be glad if I can know the reason. Thank you!

Comment: @1000111 i think your answer is correct, don't know why it has been downvoted, both find_in_set and find functions are equivalent on this context...

Comment: After being downvoted I double-checked everything. But couldn't find any issue with that. And thanks for advocating this approach @fthiella

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it worked for you @RoshanSankhe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FIELD`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `students` 
WHERE `id` IN (83, 84)
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 83, 84);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL rows are not returned in any particular order, unless you specify an order by clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `id` IN (83,84) ORDER BY ID asc
```

yes, sometimes MySQL will return rows ordered by the primary key, and sometimes it will follow the insert order, but this is not guaranteed.

If you want to return rows ordered by the IN elements, you have to specify an ORDER BY, a trick is to use the FIELD string function:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `id` IN (83,84)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 83, 84)
```

numbers will be automatically casted to strings, and FIELD(83, 83, 84) will return 1, FIELD(84, 83, 84) will return 2, anything else will return 0.