# I need to search record as per status id in some sequence

Tags: mysql

My sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/012138/1

I have following table :

> products (TABLE)
>
> ```
> id INT(10)
> productname VARCHAR(50)
> statusid INT(10)
> ```

Suppose we have following records:

```
id  productname     statusid
5   P1000              2
6   P2000              1
7   P3000              3
```

Now you can see that status id is 1,2,3.  I want to get record as per status id, but status id which we store is in different way so i can not write query to search as per order by statusid directly. Because i need to fetch record as per following status id order

first statusid 3, then status id 1 and then status id 2. How is it possible to write query ?

Comment: how many unique statusids there?

Comment: See the FIELD() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM products
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(statusid,'3,1,2')
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/012138/2/0)</kbd>

**Note:**

Add your custom sequence here `FIND_IN_SET(statusid,'3,1,2')`

**Brief note on `FIND_IN_SET`:**

**Description**

`MySQL FIND_IN_SET()` returns the position of a string if it is present (as a substring) within a list of strings. The string list itself is a string contains substrings separated by ‘,’ (comma) character.

This function returns 0 when search string does not exist in the string list and returns `NULL` if either of the arguments is `NULL`.

**Syntax**

```
FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)
```

**Arguments**

```
Name            Description
search string   A string which is to be looked for in following list of arguments.
string list     List of strings to be searched if they contain the search string.
```

[**Related post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678430/i-need-to-pull-data-based-on-its-exact-sequence-in-an-array)

<sub>Alternatively you can use `FIELD()` function to accomplish that</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Or use `FIELD`:

```
select *
from products
order by field(statusid, 3, 1, 2)
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/012138/5)