# FIND_IN_SET in cakephp not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, find-in-set

I have a table in which category ids are stored in the DB as comma separated values, so I need to search another array in this comma separated values.

Need to search `$required_ids_array` in `Posts.category_ids`

```
$required_ids_array = Array (
        [0] => 14 
        [1] => 15 
        [2] => 16 
        [3] => 25 
        [4] => 35 
);


if(isset($required_ids_array)){
    foreach ($required_ids_array as  $storeId) {
        $condition = array ();
        $condition ['AND'] ['Post.status']=1;
        $blogs = $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => $condition,
                'order' => 'Post.id.DESC',
                'limit'=>'4',
                'FIND_IN_SET(\''.$storeId.'\',Post.category_ids)')
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't get what you are asking for, please explain more.

Comment: @ArashKazemi , I have a table Posts , In that I have a Post.category_ids field in which values are saved as comma seperated. I have to search the above mentioned array '$required_ids_array' in that and fetch the values which matches that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use "find\_in\_set" in cakephp find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545045/how-to-use-find-in-set-in-cakephp-find-method)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Sehdev, No errors!

Comment: @GufranHasan, I have checked that link, but its different from my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me :)

```
$blogs = $this->Post->find ( 'all', array (
                                    'conditions' => array (
                                    'Post.status' => 1,
                                    'Post.id !=' => $id,
                                    'FIND_IN_SET(?, Post.category_ids)' => array ($storeId) ),
                            'limit' => 4,
                            'order' => 'Blog.modified DESC'  
                    ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your FIND_IN_SET condition in your WHERE condition array. You wrote it outside conditions array.

```
 $blogs = $this->Post->find('all', array 
 ('conditions' => array('Post.status' => 1, 'FIND_IN_SET(\''. $storeId 
   .'\',Post.category_ids)' )),'order' => 'Post.id 
   DESC','limit'=>'4');
```